# How to change neo4j database password

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to change my default user password to database. I've tried this:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X POST \
    -d '{"password":"password"}' \
    -u neo4j:neo4j \
    http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password"
```

but it doesn't let me and gave me this error:

> Invalid input 'u': expected 'r/R' or 'a/A' (line 1, column 2 (offset:
>   1)) "curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d
>   '{"password":"qazWSXEDCRFV!1"}' -u neo4j:neo4j
>   http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password""   ^

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You've got a dangling double quote `"` at the end of your example command and the command in the error message. I can't get bash to accept it as a command, it knows there's an open double quote. You either need to remove the double quote at the end or put another double quote at the start of your URL, that is before the `http://...`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST -d '{"password":"new password"}' -u neo4j:neo4j http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password`

just worked for me (Neo4j 3.0.x)

Comment: You can also change the password from the neo4j browser : `:POST /user/neo4j/password {"password": "myNewPassword"}`

Answer (score 7):

If you use GUI, execute :server change-password. It will call changing password dialog where you have to type your current pass and a new one.